# How to have two php echos in full calendar event start

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

So basically, I have two php echos, one with time and one with date and I want to join them both and output it to start. Basically something like this

```
start: '<?php echo $row_events['date'];?>+<?php echo $row_events['time_start'];?>',
```

But this doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't work how exactly? What is the output? Have you tried doing the concatenation in PHP instead? E.g. `<?php echo $row_events["date"]."+".$row_events["time_start"];?>`. Although...why have you got a + in the middle of the date and time? I'm not sure that's valid...maybe that's the real issue. What date format are you trying to produce?

Comment: `<?php echo $row_events['date'] .$row_events['time_start']; ?>,` this will do or if you need spaces then `<?php echo $row_events['date'].' '.$row_events['time_start']; ?>`

Answer (score 2):

I think the OP is simply trying to get the information concatenated as you wouldn't honestly add time and date together.

```
Start: '<?=$row_events['date'].' '.$row_events['time_start'];?>',
```

Could be my simplistic view of the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following line of code

```
start: <?php echo $row_events['date'] . " + ". $row_events['time_start']; ?>,
```